# How to drag features in Open Layers 3?

Tags: drag-and-drop, openlayers, openlayers-3

In the OL3 examples I can drag objects and drop on the map, but I want to **move/resize/rotate things that are already on the map** like ol.geom.Point and other ol.geom objects. What is the OL3 way do do this?

Example in OL2:

```
OpenLayers.Control.DragFeature(layer)
```

Comment: Very good question. It doesn't seem to have been implemented yet.

Answer (score 11):

Not sure why the [example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/drag-features.html) on OL3 website is so complicated. Dragging vector objects can be easily achieved using `new ol.interaction.Modify`.

[image]

Here is a simpler working example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L74gddd4/2/)

In short, if you marker was:

```
var pointFeature = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]));
```

You can define modify interaction as :

```
var dragInteraction = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: new ol.Collection([pointFeature]),
    style: null
});

map.addInteraction(dragInteraction);
```

You can then get a event for getting the new location of marker after drag like so:

```
pointFeature.on('change',function(){
            console.log('Feature Moved To:' + this.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
},pointFeature);
```

Comment: yes and it seams the translate interaction works but slightly different there is one of them that steal works on version 4 too. http://tsauerwein.github.io/ol3/animation-flights/examples/translate-features.html

Comment: Works perfectly! Great job. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [modify interaction](http://ol3js.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.interaction.Modify.html) ([example](http://ol3js.org/en/master/examples/modify-features.html)). Though rotation is not yet supported.

Answer (score -1):

I have create a simple lib that add drag interaction to openlayers 4 by slightly changing this official example:  https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-interactions.htm

you can find the lib here :
https://gist.github.com/kingofnull/0ad644be69d8dd43c05721022ca5c3a5

and you should simply add it this way:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([new ol.interaction.Drag(),])
});
```

### **Update**

I test the translate and it works in openlayer 4 and there is no need for a custom interaction. keep it in mind if you going to combine it with modify interaction you should add it before modify. here is my final code:

```
var map = new ol.Map({...});
var featureDrager = new ol.interaction.Translate();
var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({...});
map.addInteraction(featureDrager);
map.addInteraction(modify);
```